# How to use same sql in multiple places in a procedures

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In my procedures there is a sql like this
`select well_id from well where date = trunc(sysdate) - 1`
And this sql used in multiple places as query condition

```
update well_status set ... = ...
where well_id in (select well_id from well where date = trunc(sysdate) - 1)

update well_info  set ... = ...
where well_id in (select well_id from well where date = trunc(sysdate) - 1)
```

How can i use this sql as a variable or somthing that i don't need to repeat this sql inside other sql?

Comment: You can update many columns in a single update statement so why do you have many update statements all with the same condition?

Answer (score 2):

#### Option 1: Use a PL/SQL variable

If you will only ever get a single `well_id` value matching your query:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE update_well
IS
  v_well_id WELL.WELL_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT well_id
  INTO   v_well_id
  FROM   well
  WHERE  date_column = trunc(sysdate) - 1;

  update well_status
  set status = NULL
  where well_id = v_well_id;

  update well_info 
  set info = NULL
  where well_id = v_well_id;
END;
/
```

#### Option 2: Use a PL/SQL collection

If you will can get multiple `well_id` values matching your query (and want to store them all in memory while the procedure is running):

```sql
CREATE TYPE number_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_well
IS
  v_well_ids number_list;
BEGIN
  SELECT well_id
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_well_ids
  FROM   well
  WHERE  date_column = trunc(sysdate) - 1;

  update well_status
  set status = NULL
  where well_id MEMBER OF v_well_ids;

  update well_info 
  set info = NULL
  where well_id MEMBER OF v_well_ids;
END;
/
```

#### Option 3: Use a `PIPELINED` function

Define a pipelined function:

```sql
CREATE TYPE number_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE FUNCTION get_yesterday_well_ids
  RETURN number_list PIPELINED
IS
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT well_id FROM well WHERE date_column = TRUNC(sysdate) - 1)
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (r.well_id);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then use it in your procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_well
IS
BEGIN
  update well_status
  set status = NULL
  where well_id MEMBER OF get_yesterday_well_ids();

  update well_info 
  set info = NULL
  where well_id MEMBER OF get_yesterday_well_ids();
END;
/
```

#### Option 4: Use `SQL_MACRO` (from Oracle 21)

Define a macro:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_yesterday_well_id
  RETURN VARCHAR2 SQL_MACRO(TABLE)
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 'SELECT well_id FROM well WHERE date_column = TRUNC(sysdate) - 1';
END;
/
```

Then use it in your procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_well
IS
BEGIN
  update well_status
  set status = NULL
  where well_id IN (SELECT * FROM get_yesterday_well_id());

  update well_info 
  set info = NULL
  where well_id IN (SELECT * FROM get_yesterday_well_id());
END;
/
```

#### Option 5: Create a view

Create a view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW yesterday_well_id__v (well_id) AS
SELECT well_id FROM well WHERE date_column = TRUNC(sysdate) - 1;
```

Then use the view in the procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_well
IS
BEGIN
  update well_status
  set status = NULL
  where well_id IN (SELECT well_id FROM yesterday_well_id__v);

  update well_info 
  set info = NULL
  where well_id IN (SELECT well_id FROM yesterday_well_id__v);
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mxKneb-n)